# How to move the mouse in to change the color of the histogram in highcharts histogram, and restore the original color when the mouse moves out

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

[image]

As shown in the figure above, how to set the mouse to move to the column highlight to change the color of the column, and restore the original color after the mouse is moved out

Comment: so you want some mouse event handlers like [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event)?

Comment: Inside [states](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.states) you will find Options for the point state, normal, hover, select and inactive. I need to see your setting, could you prepare a simplified version of your case?